# Takes a value from website; places it into an object

Tags: javascript

I'm almost sure that this can be done more efficiently than it is, but I've spent about 30 minutes just staring at my screen. This is for a home project, but I'm using it as a way to improve my coding, so while it works, I'm almost sure that there is a better way to do this.

Effectively, on my website there is an element that contains a value (1-5). I'm accessing that value, then I want to put in into an object with a key that is titled in regards to what the value is.

I know I can iterate through the array using a for...of loop, and for...in for the object. However, since there's no way to refer to an object with it's numerical index ('cause they're unsorted, by definition), I'm not sure how I can do this.

I'm not using any libraries; I'd like to do this with pure javascript if possible. If possible, I'd also like to avoid just adding 0: "strength", 1: "dexterity",... etc. If that's not possible though, it's not a big deal if I have to, I just was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

```
var attArray = ["suStr","suDex","suSta","suPres","suMan","suCom","suInt","suWit","suRes"];
let attObj = {strength:0,dexterity:0,stamina:0,presence:0,manipulation:0,composure:0,intelligence:0,wits:0,resolve:0};

document.getElementById(attArray[0]).innerHTML = attObj.strength;
document.getElementById(attArray[1]).innerHTML = attObj.dexterity;
document.getElementById(attArray[2]).innerHTML = attObj.stamina;
document.getElementById(attArray[3]).innerHTML = attObj.presence;
document.getElementById(attArray[4]).innerHTML = attObj.manipulation;
document.getElementById(attArray[5]).innerHTML = attObj.composure;
document.getElementById(attArray[6]).innerHTML = attObj.intelligence;
document.getElementById(attArray[7]).innerHTML = attObj.wits;
document.getElementById(attArray[8]).innerHTML = attObj.resolve;
```

Comment: Please include enough contextual code so that we may advise you properly. I suggest that you add the relevant HTML as well. (Press Ctrl-M in the question editor to make a live demo.)

Comment: @200_success What really? this question does not need the HTML to understand. All the information that is needed is in the code, the markup will add nothing new to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Review to improve

Mapping named objects is a pain, makes code overly complex, and increases the chance of typos and bugs.

This review outlines 3 ways to improve. From the most basic to very advanced with a few points in regard to your original code.

You say you would like to locate attribute via a numeric index. This is possible but I can guarantee you will regret that approach very quickly.

Programmers are inherently lazy, we write code because it makes things easier to do. Many beginners miss this point and find themselves writing huge tracts of repeated names, code, tables, and whatnot. As a classic example your code

```
document.getElementById(attArray[0]).innerHTML = attObj.strength;
document.getElementById(attArray[1]).innerHTML = attObj.dexterity;
document.getElementById(attArray[2]).innerHTML = attObj.stamina;
document.getElementById(attArray[3]).innerHTML = attObj.presence;
document.getElementById(attArray[4]).innerHTML = attObj.manipulation;
document.getElementById(attArray[5]).innerHTML = attObj.composure;
document.getElementById(attArray[6]).innerHTML = attObj.intelligence;
document.getElementById(attArray[7]).innerHTML = attObj.wits;
document.getElementById(attArray[8]).innerHTML = attObj.resolve;
```

OMDG thank god for cut and paste, hey...

Good source code is what we call DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). We use functions, loops, arrays, objects and more to help reduce the amount of repeated source, and thus the amount of characters we must type and the amount of code we must keep in our heads.

In the bottom advanced example you will see that I only named all the attributes once (ignoring the HTML which was generated by a utility app on my part), yet still have a sophisticated interface.

### The simplest improvement

Your best bet is to rename the elements such that you can prefix or postfix to the existing name (`attObj` property names) to locate the element

Your HTML would look like

```
<!-- id is postfixed with El to indicate it is an element-->
<div id="strengthEl"></div>
...
<div id="manipulationEL"></div>
```

Then your code need only the `attObj`

```
const playerAtt = {strength: 0, dexterity: 0, stamina: 0, presence: 0, manipulation: 0};
for (const key of Object.keys(playerAtt)) {
    document.getElementById(key + "El").innerHTML = playerAtt[key];
}
```

**Note:** You should not need to postfix a variable type on a variables name, `attObj` would be better named `attributes`.

**Note:** The variable is a reference to (points to) the object, thus it can be a constant.

**Note:** In your question you mension `for in` FORGET you ever heard of `for in` as it has a pile of caveats a mile long and requires additional code to ensure property names belong to the object. Use `for of` instead

That is a simple fix for your problem

### More improvements

`document.getElementById` is a node query and is excruciatingly slooowwwww... compared to alternative access methods. The general practice in JavaScript when accessing elements frequently is to store them in javascript variable. You do this as part of the setup or constructing code.

```
const playerAtt = {strength: 0, dexterity: 0, stamina: 0, presence: 0, manipulation: 0};
const attElement = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(playerAtt)) { 
    attElement[key] = document.getElementById(key + "El");
}

// Then when you make changes you can access elements via the attElement obj
for (const key of Object.keys(playerAtt)) { 
    attElement[key].textContent = playerAtt[key];
}
```

**Note:** That rather than use `innerHTML` which forces a parsing, page reflow, and knock out event handlers, use `textContent` if its only text you are writing to the page. It has no parsing or reflow overheads and is safe to use with a page full of event handlers.

### Advanced version

This introduces a library type approach, with the complex code of writing and reading values from the object separated from the game code (via a separate JS file, best as a module but snippets here don't do modules).

This may be a little too much, but it is good to have in mind what can be done. There are also various frameworks that use similar approaches to this [VUE.js](https://vuejs.org/) for example (I have not looked at their code so I am guessing their approach)

#### A smarter object

We can improve how the attributes are displayed by creating a more complex attribute object that uses a setter to...

1. Vet the value so that it can only ever hold correct values.
2. Knows that the value is linked to an element and thus automatically updates the element with any changes.

.

```
const MAX_ATT_VALUE = 5;
function WatchedObj(obj, name) {
    if (!obj) {//Just incase you call the function incorrectly. Only for development.
        throw new ReferenceError("WatchedObj requires a template object.");
    }
    const contElement = name ? document.getElementById(name + "El") : document;
    function addAttribute(obj, key, value) {
        const element = contElement.querySelector("[data-attribute-name=" + key + "]");
        Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
            enumerable: true, 
            configurable: false, 
            get() { return value },
            set(val) {
                val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
                val = val < 0 ? 0 : val > MAX_ATT_VALUE ? MAX_ATT_VALUE : val; 
                if (value !== val) {
                    value = val;
                    if (element) { element.textContent = value }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    const watched = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { 
        addAttribute(watched, key, obj);
    }
    return watched;
}
```

Now that is a lot of code with some advanced concepts in it, getters, setters, closure, destructuring, and more. The point is that once written the object represent player attributes becomes nearly a no brainer.

#### Locating elements

As it is likely that you will want to display many players, you can not use the same id for more than one element as that will force the page into quirks mode, which has a pile of performance hits. So to solve the problem of locating element we can use a selector string that will find an element based on a data attribute value. eg see HTML below to find strength for player one the following selector can be used `document.querySelector("#playerOneEl [data-attribute-name=strength]");`

So the HTML will look like

```
<div id="playerOneEl">
    Strength<span data-attribute-name="strength"></span>
    Dexterity<span data-attribute-name="dexterity"></span>
    Stamina<span data-attribute-name="stamina"></span>
    Presence<span data-attribute-name="presence"></span>
    Manipulation<span data-attribute-name="manipulation"></span>
    Composure<span data-attribute-name="composure"></span>
    Intelligence<span data-attribute-name="intelligence"></span>
    Wits<span data-attribute-name="wits"></span>
    Resolve<span data-attribute-name="resolve"></span>
</div>
<div id="playerTwoEl">
    Strength<span data-attribute-name="strength"></span>
    Dexterity<span data-attribute-name="dexterity"></span>
    Stamina<span data-attribute-name="stamina"></span>
    Presence<span data-attribute-name="presence"></span>
    Manipulation<span data-attribute-name="manipulation"></span>
    Composure<span data-attribute-name="composure"></span>
    Intelligence<span data-attribute-name="intelligence"></span>
    Wits<span data-attribute-name="wits"></span>
    Resolve<span data-attribute-name="resolve"></span>
</div>
```

Another approach is to use a `<template>` and generate the player elements by cloning the template element.

#### Defining a player object

Then in the code you can define an object that is the default template for a players attributes, and a helper function

```
const DEFAULT_PLAYER_OBJECT = {
    strength: 0, dexterity: 0, stamina: 0, presence: 0, manipulation: 0, 
    composure: 0, intelligence: 0, wits: 0, resolve: 0
};
const CreatePlayer = name => WatchedObj(DEFAULT_PLAYER_OBJECT, name);
function randomizePlayer(player) {
    const randOf5 = () => Math.random() * 5 | 0;
    for (const key of player) {
        player[key] = randOf5();
    }
    return player;
}
```

Then you need only create the players. All the hard work is done for you.

```
const playerOne = randomizePlayer(CreatePlayer("playerOne")); 
const playerTwo = randomizePlayer(CreatePlayer("playerTwo"));
```

Now if you change an attribute the HTML is automatically updated as well

```
playerOne.strength = 5; // value set and HTML for player one strength is set to 5
playerTwo.wit = -5; // as it also vets the value out of range -5 is changed
                    // to 0 and displayed as 0. The -5 is total forgotten
```

### Put it into play

Making the advanced version a little more complex the example adds a color flash indicating if an attribute as increased or decreased. Yet the code to change an attribute is as basic as can be

```
playerOne.strength += 1; // If not at max the value is changed and flashes cyan.
```

```js
setTimeout(() => { // simulate page load using timer

    // create two players
    const playerOne = randomizePlayer(CreatePlayer("playerOne")); 
    const playerTwo = randomizePlayer(CreatePlayer("playerTwo")); 


    // randomly change a player attribute every 200 to 1200 ms
    function randomPlayer(){
        const randPick = array => array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];
        var attName = randPick(Object.keys(DEFAULT_PLAYER_OBJECT));
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            playerOne[attName] += Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            playerTwo[attName] += Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        }
        setTimeout(randomPlayer, Math.random() * 1000 + 200);

    }
    randomPlayer();

},0);

/* Library scroll down*/





















// Code below can be in another library js file and common to all pages.


const DEFAULT_PLAYER_OBJECT = {strength: 0, dexterity: 0, stamina: 0, presence: 0, manipulation: 0, composure: 0, intelligence: 0, wits: 0, resolve: 0};
function CreatePlayer(name) { return WatchedObj(DEFAULT_PLAYER_OBJECT, name) }
// to create random settings
function randomizePlayer(player) {
    const randOf5 = () => Math.random() * 5 | 0;
    for (const key of Object.keys(player)) {
        player[key] = randOf5();
    }
    return player;
}


const MAX_ATT_VALUE = 5;
const FLASH_TIME = 500; // time in ms of flash
const UP_FLASH_CLASS = "upFlash"; // name of class
const DOWN_FLASH_CLASS = "downFlash"; // name of class
function WatchedObj(obj, name) {

    if (!obj) {  // just incase you call the function incorrectly. This is only for development.
        throw new ReferenceError("WatchedObj requires a template object.");
    }
    const containingElement = name ? document.getElementById(name + "El") : document;
    function addAttribute(obj, name, value) {
        var flashTimer, lastFlash = "";
        const element = containingElement.querySelector("[data-attribute-name=" + name + "]");
        const contEl = element.parentElement;
        Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
            enumerable: true,  
            configurable: false, 
            get() { return value },
            set(val) {
                val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;  // max it a number if not already so
                val = val < 0 ? 0 : val > MAX_ATT_VALUE ? MAX_ATT_VALUE : val; // make sure is in range
                if (value !== val) { // only if the new value is different

                    if (element) { // only if the element has been found
                        clearTimeout(flashTimer);
                        if (lastFlash !== ""){
                            contEl.classList.remove(lastFlash);
                        }
                        lastFlash = val < value ? DOWN_FLASH_CLASS : UP_FLASH_CLASS;
                        element.textContent = val;                    
                        contEl.classList.add(lastFlash);
                        flashTimer = setTimeout(() => contEl.classList.remove(lastFlash), 500);
                    }
                    value = val;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    const watched = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { // for each key value pair create a property
        addAttribute(watched, key, obj);
    }
    return watched;
}
```

```css
 .player {
    display: inline-grid;
    width : 150px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.playerAtt {
}

span {
   text-align: right;
}
.playerAtt span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
.upFlash {
   background : #09F;
   animation-duration: 0.25s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in;
   animation-fill-mode: both;   
   animation-name: fadeOut;
}
.downFlash {
   background : red;
   animation-duration: 0.25s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in;
   animation-fill-mode: both;   
   animation-name: fadeOut;
   
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {}
  100% { background: #FFF; }
}
```

```html
    <div id="playerOneEl" class="player">
        <div>Player One</div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Strength<span data-attribute-name="strength"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Dexterity<span data-attribute-name="dexterity"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Stamina<span data-attribute-name="stamina"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Presence<span data-attribute-name="presence"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Manipulation<span data-attribute-name="manipulation"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Composure<span data-attribute-name="composure"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Intelligence<span data-attribute-name="intelligence"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Wits<span data-attribute-name="wits"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Resolve<span data-attribute-name="resolve"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="playerTwoEl" class="player">
        <div>Player Two</div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Strength<span data-attribute-name="strength"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Dexterity<span data-attribute-name="dexterity"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Stamina<span data-attribute-name="stamina"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Presence<span data-attribute-name="presence"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Manipulation<span data-attribute-name="manipulation"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Composure<span data-attribute-name="composure"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Intelligence<span data-attribute-name="intelligence"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Wits<span data-attribute-name="wits"></span></div>
        <div class="playerAtt">Resolve<span data-attribute-name="resolve"></span></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's almost always a more elegant solution that "manually" iterating through an array. Instead of defining `attArray`, you can define a mapping object that maps element ids to `attObj` properties, or `attObj` properties to element ids.

```js
const attributeToIdMap = {
  strength: "suStr",
  dexterity: "suDex",
  ...
```

Demo:

```js
const attributeToIdMap = {
  strength: "suStr",
  dexterity: "suDex",
  stamina: "suSta",
  presence: "suPres",
  manipulation: "suMan",
  composure: "suCom",
  intelligence: "suInt",
  wits: "suWit",
  resolve: "suRes"
};

const attributes = {
  strength: 0,
  dexterity: 0,
  stamina: 0,
  presence: 0,
  manipulation: 0,
  composure: 0,
  intelligence: 0,
  wits: 0,
  resolve: 0
};

// Create the HTML for the demo
const root = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
for (const [attribute, id] of Object.entries(attributeToIdMap)) {
  const li = root.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(attribute + ': '));
  const attributeElement = li.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
  attributeElement.id = id;
}

// Loop through attributes
for (const [attribute, id] of Object.entries(attributeToIdMap)) {
  document.getElementById(id).textContent = attributes[attribute];
}
```

Alternatively, since in this case the element ids can be derived from the attribute name, you can do away with the `attributeToIdMap` object and apply the transformation. With your current id setup, this probably isn't a great idea since the mapping isn't immediately obvious, but if the ids were renamed to something like `attribute + 'El'`, it would be immediately clear what each element belonged to.

```js
function getId(attribute) {
  return `su${attribute[0].toLocaleUpperCase()}${attribute.substring(1, 3)}`;
}
```

Demo:

```js
function getId(attribute) {
  return `su${attribute[0].toLocaleUpperCase()}${attribute.substring(1, 3)}`;
}

const attributes = {
  strength: 0,
  dexterity: 0,
  stamina: 0,
  presence: 0,
  manipulation: 0,
  composure: 0,
  intelligence: 0,
  wits: 0,
  resolve: 0
};

// Create the HTML for the demo
const root = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
for (const attribute of Object.keys(attributes)) {
  const li = root.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(attribute + ': '));
  const attributeElement = li.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
  attributeElement.id = getId(attribute);
}

// Loop through attributes
for (const [attribute, value] of Object.entries(attributes)) {
  document.getElementById(getId(attribute)).textContent = value;
}
```

I have a few other concerns about your code as well:

1. Nonstandard abbreviations don't help. You will spend much more time reading code than writing it. Abbreviating `att` means that someone unfamiliar with the context wonders does this mean "AT&T", "attribute", "attrition"? Standard abbreviations like `min`, `max`, etc. are obviously fine.
2. Don't mix `var` and `let`. If you can, use `let` (or even `const`)
3. If possible, avoid `.innerHTML`. By using it you can open yourself up to XSS if the user is ever able to control the input. Prefer `.textContent`.

Comment: As far as concerns about my code;

1. I'm a bit dyslexic, and I have a tendency to misspell attribute, and later not track down the misspelling. I generally avoid shorthand in my variable names, but in this particular case, I am less likely to make a mistake.

2. The var is actually a global variable that I use in other parts in the code. In my actual script it's 100's of lines away; I just pulled into this snippet for clarity. I tend to use let.

3. What is XXS? The input is controllable, but only through a button that increments or decrements a number. Should I be worried?

Comment: 1. Autocomplete is great, tab is probably my most used character. 3. Typo, sorry, should have been XSS. You are probably fine since this is just numbers. XSS generally sneaks in when outputting text from a user.

Comment: I use Notepad++, so I don't really have a spellcheck. I think there might be a plugin or something; I'll take a look around

Comment: Point 1. Abbreviations as in `Math`  `min`, `max` and `cos` it's not `minimum`, `maximum`, and `cosine`. Tokens `var`, `const` are abbreviations for `variable` and `constant` Abbreviations make code easier to read and reduce the number of long lines that often must be split. Code complete does not read the code for you and many coders prefer to not use such tools. Learning common abbreviations and using them is an important part of writing good code.

Comment: Point 2. Is function scope too difficult? Did you know that `let`  declarations can be a huge source mem over use example `var i=1000; while(i--){ let a = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024); setTimeout(()=>{}) };` uses 1Gig of mem while `var a,i=1000; while(i--){ a = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024); setTimeout(()=>{}) };` uses a few Mb. Beginners should not be advised to avoid difficult parts, they learn nothing from that. Rather you should explain when it is prefered to use parts of the language and when it's not such a good idea, including the why

Comment: And your advice to map names is adding complexity with no advantage, Why not advise the OP to change the element ids to a more conducive form eg using a postfix `<div id="strengthEl">` can be found post fixing attribute name with "El" making the need for a map redundant. However point 3 is a good point +1

Comment: @Blindman67 1 - fair point, I should clarify that I mean nonstandard abbreviations. `att` could mean a ton of different things, I certainly wouldn't advise spelling out `ast` all the time.

Comment: 2. No, not too difficult, it just leads to less clear code. In your example I wouldn't be surprised if the declaration outside of the loop has a bug, and if it doesn't, there's still no harm in using `let` outside the loop.
3. Mapping names - good point regarding choosing different ids, the mapping might still be useful if element ids are out of your control.

Comment: Code in comment? No bug, func in `setTimeout` closes over `let a` 1Mb array each iter * 1000~1Gig `var` is safer. Block Scope (BS) being safer is a myth, with no evidence in support. BS came from C like languages as a natural step from ASM, optimising register, memory, and now cache use, BS gave performance benefits. It's been corrupted into being safe (likely due to many C coders confused about JS scope) BS is useful only. Loops using let are slower than var counters. Functional style code with BS chews memory. Im personally near advocating var over let due to the problems inherent in its use

Comment: Eeeek I just reread my comment. Everything past 1Gig is a rant, not directed at you, rather anyone that may read it. (likely no one LOL)